# Keycloak-admin-client nagging resteasy jakarta form error in 22.0.5

Tags: java, maven, keycloak, jakarta-migration, keycloak-admin-client

I am trying to build a jar that can execute simple keycloak configuration. I am using the keycloak-admin-client and newest keycloak version 22.0.5. However after trying many different options in dependecies and even the quarkus-keycloak-admin-client. I constantly get stuck on;

```
Exception in thread "main" jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request: jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/x-www-form-urlencoded type: jakarta.ws.rs.core.Form$1
```

I know that spring 2 > 3 also has some javax to jakarta migration troubles, but In this I do not have a way to solve this. What is this writer I am looking for and am I understanding it correctly that it goes wrong at the constructor of Form?

```
 public Form(MultivaluedMap<String, String> store) {
        this.parameters = store;
    }
```

The java version is openjdk 17.0.9 LTS
The commands I run are simply mvn clean package and java -jar jarfile
The current pom.xml I have is;

```
 <parent>
    <groupId>config.keycloak</groupId>
    <artifactId>keycloak-config-tryout</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</parent>

<artifactId>java-configuration</artifactId>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    <resteasy.version>6.2.6.Final</resteasy.version>
    <keycloak.version>22.0.5</keycloak.version>
    <maven.jar.plugin.version>3.3.0</maven.jar.plugin.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.26</lombok.version>


</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-admin-client</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-client</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson2-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${resteasy.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
        <artifactId>keycloak-services</artifactId>
        <version>${keycloak.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Tooling-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.jar.plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven.shade.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>config.keycloak.KeycloakConfigurationApplication</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                        <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.jar</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing from

```xml
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/services/javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers</resource>
</transformer>
```

to

```xml
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
    <resource>META-INF/services/jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers</resource>
</transformer>
```

Both files were renamed in resteasy-client and resteasy-jackson2-provider from `javax.ws.rs.ext.Providers` to `jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers`

See [here](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/blob/main/resteasy-client/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers) for resteasy-client and [here](https://github.com/resteasy/resteasy/blob/main/providers/jackson2/src/main/resources/META-INF/services/jakarta.ws.rs.ext.Providers) for resteasy-jackson2-provider